# Slim Set Middleware

Tags: php, middleware, slim

What's the right way to set a custom middleware for a specific route calling setMiddleware method? I wrote a custom Middleware:

**CustomMiddleware**

```
namespace Slim\Middleware;

class CustomMiddleware extends \Slim\Middleware {
    public function __construct() {
        // omitted
    }

    public function call() {
        // omitted
    }
}
```

**Then I want to set that to a specific route:**

```
$app->get(
        '/api/users(/)', function () use ($app) {
    echo 'Middleware passed.';
})->setMiddleware(new \Slim\Middleware\CustomMiddleware());
```

Using it this way I get:

```
InvalidArgumentException: Route middleware must be callable or an array of callables in C:\dev\rest\Slim\Route.php on line 336
```

Any help? Many thanks.

Comment: is there any PHP-error in your Middleware call()-function? I know this behaviour when theres an error in it.

Comment: Call function in currently empty.

Comment: Ok due to https://github.com/codeguy/Slim/blob/master/Slim/Route.php the setMiddleware is checking if provided param is callable. The behaviour of `is_callable()` can be seen here: http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.is-callable.php. Since you don't provide a method but a class (extending Middleware) `is_callable()` will result in `false`. Just try `->setMiddleware(function());` to verify this.

Comment: k, I've tried ->setMiddleware(function(){}) and no exceptions are shown...but hey I need to set the middleware not an anonymous function =)

Comment: Well yeah. It was just to verify this. Ok. 

Usual you could pass an array to `is_callable()` (see docs http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.is-callable.php) with Class-Objct as first entry and method name as second entry. Since Slim will not pass that array to is_callable() but instead looping the array this won't work.

Erm... Since I did'nt work with Route-Middleware yet I'm out of this. I'm sorry :(

Comment: No problem, I'll go with the specific help page. Thank you anyway.